# Node/Express Form handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am following a tutorial to build a node/express app using the jade templating engine and I am getting a 404 error when I try to submit a form. For my routing I have the line `app.post('/sign_up', sign_up);` which gives me an error. The `sign_up`variable is declared above using this line `var sign_up = require('./routes/sign_up');`.

The strange thing is if I register a callback function in the place of the `sign_up` variable then I can retrieve the data fine, which I did using this code 
`app.post('/sign_up', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
});`.

In my routes folder I have got the *sign_up.js* file and which outputs a rather simple line of text. I have tried changing the function

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('You signed up');
});
module.exports = router;
```

Below are the contents of my *form.jade* file

```
    extends layout
    block content
    h1= title
    form(name="sign-up", action="/sign_up", method="post")
        div
            label Username: 
            input(type="text", name="username")
        div
            label Password: 
            input(type="password", name="password")
        div
            input(type="submit", value="Sign Up")
```

Comment: Take a look at the question I think this is a duplicate of. You are confused about the way you declare routes in external files.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Like I said I am following a tutorial and that was what is in the tutorial. Thank you however for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sign_up.js to handle the routing, then you should define the post function there. Try to add this in sign_up.js

```
/* POST*/
router.post('/sign_up', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('You signed up');
});
```

Comment: This solved me problem. Thank you very much. Its odd because the other paths all used '/' and they worked fine so in the users.js file the '/users' path is defined as                                                     `router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});`                                                                                                                          Can you explain why that works and the other doesn't?

Comment: The others are using `router.get`, for post method, you need to use `router.post`.
If you need Put, in the future, you will need to use `router.put` as well.
If you need to have a global handler for all http methods, you can use `router.all` too.

Comment: What I was asking was why is it you can navigate to _http://localhost:3000/users_ even the the route for that path is `router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { res.send('respond with a resource'); });` which is inside the users.js file? When I put `router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) { res.send('respond with a resource'); });` in the users.js file, I get a 404 error.

Comment: do you have `app.use('/users', users);` in app.js?

Comment: Yes I do, I also had `app.post('/sign_up', sign_up);`. Is it that syntax cannot work? It appears to be a really poor tutorial, I guess I will just continue and see what I can learn for now. Have you got any suggestions for any better tutorials that I can use.

Comment: I think i was using the same tutorial too. When you pass the url in `app.use()`, that becomes the basepath of the route. So if you have `/users` in app.js and also in the router, the route it binds to actually is `/users/users`, you only need '/users' in one or the others, but not in both places.